# How to write a CSV file after reading it with CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper, system.io.file

I need to write a `HttpPostedFileBase` csv (and save it) after mapping it into a list using the CsvHelper nuget package. However, after mapping it with CsvHelper, the `ContentLength` is 0, and I end up saving an empty .csv file.

CsvHelper itself states that the Read method should not be used when using the `GetRecords<T>()` method.

```
        // Summary:
        //     Gets all the records in the CSV file and converts each to System.Type T. The
        //     Read method should not be used when using this.
        //
        // Type parameters:
        //   T:
        //     The System.Type of the record.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     An System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 of records.
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T>();
```

I tried placing it into a copy variable:

```
HttpPostedFileBase csvCopy = csvFile;
```

But this didn't work. Tried some other solutions I found on stackoverflow, which didn't work either. I "solved" this problem by sending the same file twice to the controller as a parameter. Then I use the first one with CsvHelper, and I read and save the other one.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ImportCSV(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile, HttpPostedFileBase csvFileCopy)
```

However, I think this is a bad solution. I would like to use a single file, map it, reread it and save it.

Mapping it into a list:

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(csvFile.InputStream)) {
   using(var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader)) {
    csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new CSVModelMap(mapDictionary));
    csvReader.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;
    csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
    csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
    importData = csvReader.GetRecords<CSVModel>().ToList();    
   }
 }
```

Saving it:

```
var fileName = serverPath + "\\" + hashedFileName;
CheckIfDirectoryExists(serverPath);
var reader = new StreamReader(csvFile.InputStream);
var csvContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
File.WriteAllText(fileName, csvContent);
```

Comment: Your saving example doesnt look complete.. if you have read to the end of the stream, you would need to go back to the start - I thought however the point was to write out your mapped version not just save the stream..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was CsvHelper:

```
using(var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
```

At the end of the using statement, `CsvReader` closes the reader. Then when I try

```
csvFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

or

```
reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
```

it throws a `NullReferenceException`. I solved this by simply overriding the `CsvReader`:

```
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, true))
```

`true` being `leaveOpen`:

```
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a new CSV reader using the given System.IO.TextReader.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   reader:
        //     The reader.
        //
        //   leaveOpen:
        //     true to leave the reader open after the CsvReader object is disposed, otherwise
        //     false.
        public CsvReader(TextReader reader, bool leaveOpen);
```

Then I set the position back to 0, using `reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;`, and then after saving the file, dispose the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not to sure how GetRecords works, but there might be the possibility that it leaves the cursor on the stream pointed towards the end.

Meaning on your saving sequence you start reading the InputStream at the end, which results in no data to read.

So you could try

```
csvFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

EDIT:

For your try to copy the stream you only copy the reference to the object and not the object itself. 
To copy the stream data you would need to use the method `CopyTo(stream)` which would leave the cursor on the end of the stream, so here seek is needed for sure.